# I'd like to add an fa icon before a link in my 'recent post' side bar

Tags: sidebar

Similar to your 'how to format' side bar----> 
I've got the code that will pull the icon  the question is: where do I insert that, so that with every new post a link appears in the side bar with the icon in front.

It might be solved through css, but that is not the answer I am seeking. I am sure that the code to invoke an arrow can be inserted into the php.

The question is which php file do I need to modify in order to achieve this.

Comment: You might consider editing your question to provide a little more detail. What have you already tried, for example? As things stand, the only thing I would suggest at the moment is looking for sidebar.php in your theme and editing there.

Comment: I already had a look at sidebar.php but there is just a comment saying 
/*  * Required by WordPress, but not used in PageLines. */
So I contacted the peeps at pageline (dms theme) and their answer to the question above is as follow: You will need to use a hook. However, we are unable to provide assistance or the code required to achieve this. As that widget is a WordPress core widget. You will need to ask this question on the WordPress support forums.

I thought if I could find the file that outputs the links in the side bar, I could just insert the code in front of the url

Does this clarify?

Comment: Was about to write an answer like the one below. Seems like a way to go, though not really Wordpress specific.

Comment: closing it as it is a CSS/HTML question and not a wordpress one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to ask you in comments: Could would be nice, to show what you want to achieve, but you are maybe wondering about this in CSS (if you have implemented FontAwesome already):

```
yourlement:before { //replace with your element
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f061"; //replace with your icon
}
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kybernaut/203ucwf8/)

Comment: Thank you I had tried this method but the code provided by fa looks looks this:
<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>

would you know what content to use to display the right-arrow as in:

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/arrow-right/

Comment: @DidierSajno Every icon from font awesome has as well the css content value, the list is [here](http://www.weisbergweb.com/FontAwesome-CSS-Values/), arrow-right should looks like: "\f061"

Comment: @DidierSajno I have added jsfidle link into my answer

Comment: thanks, but for some reasons it shows as a square

Comment: Check that the path to your CSS file is correct. And be careful, you shouldn't have both `font-awesome.css` and `font-awesome.min.css` at one time.